# Angular - Get router url before loading router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use my app as an iframe on other web pages. However, therefore I need a 'stripped' version of my app, where some features are disabled.

Normally, I navigate with url/#/... For the iframe, it is url/#/iframe/... . They both navigate to the same pages, although some features are disabled in the latter.

My problem is that I want to place a `div` around the `router-outlet` with a class depending on whether I'm in iframe-mode or not. At this moment, I can only think of checking

```
this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'iframe'
```

in the car.component.ts file, storing this value somewhere in app.service.ts as `appService.iframe` and then using this value in app.component.html.

This, however, gives the following error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'body1'. Current value: 'body2'.
```

Can I get the url before loading the router?

**app.routes.ts file:**

```
// Route Configuration
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: CarList},
  {path: 'iframe', component: CarList},
  {path: 'iframe/:loket', component: Car},
  {path: ':loket', component: Car}
];

// Export routes
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**app.component.html file:**

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <header></header>
      </div>  
      <div [ngClass]="(!appService.iframe) ? 'body1': 'body2'">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <footer></footer>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose you can use the native `location.hash` value and check from there

Comment: That did the job! Used `this.appState.iframe = location.hash.includes("iframe")` in the constructor of app.component.ts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the native `location.hash` you can determine if it includes the iframe value:

```
location.hash.includes("iframe")
```